# How can I fix npm error running npm run build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I run npm run build, I had this error and I couldn't fix it reading all articles on github and same quest-s on stack:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Користувач\Desktop\test/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Користувач\Desktop\test\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Користувач\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-06T18_36_44_973Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Are you in the right folder? Is there a `package.json` file in that folder?

Comment: Looks like you're not in the correct location in terminal. Try to `cd` into the project folder where there is a package.json file and there's a `build` script in there as well

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are trying to run the build command in non node project please check whether you are in correct directory or not, if not please initialize the project by running `npm init`

Answer (score 0):

ensure you're in the correct directory. You need to cd into the right directory before running the command.

If you want to make sure package.json is there in the directory, run

```sh
ls | grep package.json
```

if this doesn't show the file, then either you're in the wrong directory or you might have deleted package.json in which case you might have to recreate it, or bring it back from version control.

Comment: OP is on Windows

Comment: OP can use ls on windows with wsl or the equivalent dir command piped with findstr to check